# Bounded improper integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, nonlinear-analysis

If $x(t)$ is a solution of a globally asymptotically stable second-order ODE,
$$\ddot{x}(t) + \alpha \dot{x}(t) + g(x(t)) = 0,$$
where $g(x)$ is an smooth non-linear function which is everywhere continuous and differentiable as well as integrable and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_ {>0} $ and if $\|x(t)\|$ is $\mathrm{C}^3$ and $\int_{0} ^{\infty}\tau||\dot{x}(\tau)||^4d\tau < \infty$, then $t||\dot{x}(t)||^2$ is convergent. Are there any exceptions to this inference?

Comment: So the question is if there can be an infinity of ever narrower spikes in the solution of a quite regular autonomous second order DE. One could use the energy function $H(x,\dot x)=\frac12\dot x^2+G(x)$, $G'=g$, to gain further insight into the dynamics.

Comment: If you look at the system carefully, your energy function is indeed the Lyapunov function. The place where I am stuck is, would it ever be possible for the integral of such a function with infinitely many spikes to be a solution to this autonomous ODE.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point of the question but if the system is globally asymptotically stable then its solutions remain bounded... so any unbounded function can't be a solution of the system.

Comment: @SampleTime No, you aren't, I have removed that part as it is a direct implication of the second theorem of Lyapunov.